# How to change MongoDB dbPath from linux command line?

Tags: linux, mongodb

What command should I use to change the `dbPath` setting of MongoDB installed on a linux system? The default settings are found in `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean change the conf file without a editor? If yes, you could use 'sed'

```
$ sed -i 's@/var/lib/mongodb@/your/new/directory/here@g' configfile
```

or if you want to change just dbPath:

```
$ sed -i '/dbPath/s/:.*/: \/your\/new\/directory\/here' configfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the dbPath option when starting mongo like

`mongod --dbpath /srv/mongodb/`

if you don't want to mess with the config file. Say if you have two mongo data directories on one machine, you can start up mongo with different data this way. Or you could just open up the .conf file in a text editor and change it, or use the `sed` approach by @mulatinho to change it.